# Error: "Undefined control sequence" in \includegraphics, height

Tags: floats, subfloats, height

I am using `figure` and `subfigure` environment. Inside `subfigure` I am using `includegraphics`. The `figure` and `subfigure` structure looks like following:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{building1}
    \caption{\textit{\small{building1}}}
    \label{fig:1a}    
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.75\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,height=100\lineheight pt,keepaspectratio]{building2}
    \caption{\textit{\small{building2}}}
    \label{fig:1b}  
\end{subfigure}
\caption{\textit{\small{Buildings}}}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
```

For the first `subfigure`, everything is OK. But for the second I am getting the build error: `Undefined control sequence. ...t pt,keepaspectratio]{building2}`. It seems the problem lies with using the `height` attribute in the second `subfigure`, as when I removed the `height` attribute from the second `subfigure`, there was no build error.

What is the reason of this? Is there a way to keep using both `height` and `width` attributes in `includegraphics`?

P.S.: I am using `\usepackage{subcaption}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  `\lineheight` is not defined by default.  Perhaps you want `\baselineskip` instead.

Comment: `height=100\baselineskip` should instead be something like `height=0.85\textheight` to allow space for the caption.

Comment: `\lineheight pt` <- maybe the `pt` is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, LaTeX has no parameter `\lineheight`. I guess that may be you mean `\baselineskip` instead which is the stand vertical space between the corresponding points of lines in text.

Replacing `\lineheight` with `\baselineskip` removes the error, but has no effect in your case, as you have also specified the `width` and `keepaspectratio`.  You should remove one of these extra specification to allow the resizing to take place.  I have chose to remove `keepaspectratio` below.

You will then discover that `100\baselineskip` is more than a standard page height, so in the example below I have reduced this to `10\baselinkeskip`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\captionsetup{font=small,textfont=it}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.25\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Building 1}
    \label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.75\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth,height=10\baselineskip]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Building 2}
    \label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Buildings}
\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In the above, I have also used a `\captionsetup` command to specify uniform styling of the captions.  This avoids having to write `\small\textit` in each case, and leads to more consistency.